# Ionic 3 - Child page ( push page ) invoking the parent page method

Tags: ionic3

```
I have a root page invoking the method1 on event ( change ) (change)="dateChanged1()" for checkbox. 
and on button click navigating to page2 using push method.
In page2, having checkbox with (change)="dateChanged2()". 

Whenever i click on page2 checkbox, it is invoking the page1 method. Can anyone help me on this ?
```

Change event is available in older version of Ionic.
If i use ionchange, nothing working for me.

For change event, Page1 - working as expected. but in page2, change event invoking the page1 method.

This behaviour is worked properly in older version. but after i upgrade to latest ionic, this seems not working. 
Is there any workaround for solve this issue.

```
**Page1 ::**

 <div class="btn-group col-sm-12 noleftpadding norightpadding margin-top-40-per" style="width:100%" class="custompaddingforsearch" col-12>
                                                 <div class="checkboxgrp col-sm-12 noleftpadding norightpadding" style="width:100%">
                                                   <div  col-2 class="availsun availbox  col-sm-1" style="float: left;" >
                                                       <input type="checkbox" class="availcheck " id="availsun" name="availsun" value="SUNDAY" (change)="dateChanged2()"/>
                                                       <label for="availsun"><p class="availtitle">SUN</p></label>
                                                   </div>
                                                     <div  col-2 class="availmon availbox col-sm-1" style="float: left;" >
                                                         <input type="checkbox" class="availcheck " id="availmon" name="availmon" value="MONDAY" (change)="dateChanged2()">
                                                         <label for="availmon"><p class="availtitle">MON</p></label>
                                                     </div>
    </div>
</div>

**Page 2::**


  <div class="btn-group col-sm-12 noleftpadding norightpadding custommarginprofile" style="width:100%" col-12>
    <div class="checkboxgrp col-sm-12 noleftpadding norightpadding" style="width:100%">
      <div  col-2 class="availsun availbox  col-sm-1" style="float: left;" *ngIf="sunavail != '' ">
        <input type="checkbox" class="availcheck" id="availsun" name="availsun" value="0" (change)="dateChanged1('0')"/>
        <label for="availsun"><p class="availtitle">SUN</p></label>
      </div>
      <div  col-2 class="availmon availbox col-sm-1" style="float: left;"  *ngIf="monavail != '' ">
        <input type="checkbox"  class="availcheck " id="availmon" name="availmon" value="1" (change)="dateChanged1('1')">
        <label for="availmon"><p class="availtitle">MON</p></label>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>



Ionic Info ::


cli packages: (C:\Users\hi\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.0
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.19.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 1.3.7
    Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.3.0

System:

    Node : v6.11.4
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 10

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Comment: you can try `(ionChange)` [link](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/checkbox/Checkbox/); also please share your code

Comment: I have used the below html code .

Comment: <input type="checkbox" class="availcheck " id="availsun" name="availsun" value="SUNDAY" (change)="dateChanged2()"/>

Comment: I can't find a `(change)` event in ionic docs. I was saying to post all relevant code in your issue description above